# How to add value to a specific row in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I want to add weight value to row 2. How do I do that? I tried to do the following but it gives me an error:

```
INSERT INTO name(member_id, weight) VALUES(2,55.6);
```

What is the mistake that I'm having?

[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Do you mean you are trying to change the `weight` column value of the second row? If so, you need to update the row by `member_id` column. If you're trying to add a column to an existing table, you'll need an `ALTER TABLE` statement, something like: `ALTER TABLE table
ADD [COLUMN] column_name column_definition [FIRST|AFTER existing_column];`. [You can find more info here:](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-add-column/)

Answer (score 1):

If you're updating a specific row you need to use the [UPDATE](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp) command

`UPDATE talbename
   SET weight =55.6
   WHERE member_id = 2`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `UPDATE` clause and use a `WHERE` condition to target a particular row -

```
UPDATE fromis_9
SET weight = 2
WHERE member_id = 2;
```

Comment: Out of range value for column 'weight' at row 1, this is the error

Comment: Well, your `CREATE TABLE` statement (from your screenshot) shows that you didn't add the `weight` column at the time of creating the table. Did you add in the correct data type when you added it in later?

Answer (score 1):

`INSERT INTO` clause is used for inserting new records.
To Update an existing record, `UPDATE` clause is used.

```
UPDATE fromis_9 SET weight = 55.6 WHERE member_id = 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi I think you should use INSERT INTO table
where condition(member.id=2)
please refer to https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp
Its better to learn how to read documentation than wait for complete answer ;)

Comment: I agree with answer below, i forgot that if  you are inserting something in existing row you need to use update instad of insert (Too much spring)